# To share dynamically network between OSX and Virtual OS

Tags: macos, network, wifi, virtualization, virtualbox

My colleges say that OS cannot dynamically share network between two OS, in contrast to Windows. 
One college solved the problem by ethernet connection and external network card, discussed [here](http://Oleophobic%20thin%20film%20coatings).
However, I know that this is possible to solve also programmatically.

I think the tools required for this are

- LXC and Vagrant, discussed [here](http://taoofmac.com/space/HOWTO/Vagrant)

I think this is what is wanted here

[image]

### Setting parasite host

In Network settings, I cannot change *Attached to* to *Host-only Adapter*. 
I have to keep the bridged mode:

[image]

Details

- host OS Yosemite 10.10.3
- Virtual OS Cern Linux 5, based on Redhat; I think this is virtual OS independent

How can you share network card dynamically between OSX and Virtual OS?
You can choose whatever virtualization you want, but my colleges use VirtualBox because it is freely available. 
Our Virtual OS is CERN Linux 5 which has GNU development tools 2013 i.e. a variant of Redhat.

Comment: What is the host OS version and build? Are you willing to pay for software that implements this? The pragmatic solution I use is add a USB hub with enough cheap NIC to allocate one to each VM that demands total control over the network interface. I'm going to clear the close votes since with this detail - it's clearly a good technical challenge/question.

Comment: @bmike I added details host OS and virtual Os. This thread is probably mostly a plan. Many universities and my colleges solve this problem by paying ethernet adapter and 2nd network card so I think you can charge for the final product such as service cost etc. My goal is to make this just freely available for everyone. So your implementation puts something to USB port with some controller there which controls the network card and allocates network to both OSs. There must be some gap in such an implementation because of USB and its limitation. My friend did it with thunderbolt + device.

Comment: I agree it's technically feasible. You just tell the host OS to keep it's hands off the adapter and ensure the virtualization software can locate and load the drivers for the hardware and take over for the OS loading drivers and handling the interrupts. You'll find that this depends on chipsets so what works on a 2012 MBP might not on other models or years of the same "product". I hope there is a general solution as I know several orgs hoping to use Mac Pro to virtualize more diverse workloads.

Comment: @bmike There is some semi-general solution but I do not know how it can technically done. I have seen people doing it and switching smoothly from different Mac to another.